# Translation: "Shape" (as in "in shape" / "out of shape")

Tags: translation

how to translate `shape` as in: to be "in shape" or to be "out of shape"?

just `健康`?

Comment: good shape 良好的体态， be in bad shape 健康情况不佳、处于不良的健康状况 out of shape  体质差 ，
nciku：I'm out of shape for beach activity.
    我身体不适合海滩活动。
She joined aerobics to keep in shape
她参加健身舞以保持良好的体态
iciba：The former hostage is in remarkably good shape considering his ordeal.
    想想人质曾遭受的折磨，获救后其身体状况已经是出奇地好了The old actor is still in good shape.
    那老演员身体还很健康.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, `shape` can be translated in to "身材". `in shape` means "好身材，健康" `out of shape`means "身材走样"

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context. I would suggest using 健康状况(很好/不太好) to express one's general health status (very good/not so good). If you are trying to tell someone to cut down on icecream, use wanglan8498's answer, or the word 体态 (visual status of the body) to encourage one to hit the gym. I think the word "shape" as used here can be roughly translated into 状态, but the connotation of being slightly casual is perhaps lost.

Answer (score 0):

"in shape" can be means having good muscle tone. In Chinese can be translate as "强壮"

"out of shape" can be means skinny / weak people / have a bad physical stamina. In Chinese can be translate as "瘦弱/软弱“

Answer (score 0):

In this content, shape: 狀態

In shape / In good shape: 狀態良好
In bad shape / Out of shape: 狀態惡劣

When you're referring to physically In shape / out of shape you could use 體態